# Specific module breaks HMR on my entire application

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-hmr

I am using hot.accept in the root of my application, and so far it's worked brilliantly.

```
var hot = (<any>module).hot;
if (hot) {
    hot.accept();
}
```

However, since I migrated to Angular 2 RC5, and use their module system, I have run into issues. Specifically the issue I run into is with the `ReactiveFormsModule` in "@angular/forms".

Having this in my application breaks HMR for my entire application. How do I account for this third party module and make sure it gets accepted?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the cause for this issue was that I had failed to add `@angular/forms` into my webpack entry import list.

```
// Angular 2
import "@angular/platform-browser";
import "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import "@angular/core";
import "@angular/common";
import "@angular/forms"; // was commented out
import "@angular/http";
import "@angular/router";
```

Adding this in resolved the issue immediately.